# Separate exception handler for PDO

Tags: php, pdo, exception

In my PHP code, I have several types of exceptions. One is a 'normal' `Exception`, another is `PDOException`. I'm using `set_exception_handler($handler)` to catch exceptions automatically.

Is there any way I can get separate handlers for Exception and PDOException?
If not, can I check the type of the exception in the handler?

Comment: @YourCommonSense because I want to handle PDOExceptions in an other way than Exceptions. Do I say something stupid?

Comment: I quite understand that. Why do you want to handle PDOExceptions in an other way? Or rather what you're going to do with PDO exceptions?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I want to log PDOExceptions to a file, while I want to output something to the user for a normal Exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should have a "global" handler, and branch.

```
set_exception_handler(function ($exception) {
  if ($exception instanceof PDOException) {
    handle_pdo_exception($exception);
    return;
  }
  log($exception);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for clarifying your question.

I think you are asking out of wrong assumption.

As a matter of fact, either normal exception needs to be logged to a common `error_log` and PDOexception have to trigger a generic 500 error page shown to user. There is no point in separating these matters. So, you can use common exception handler to handle all exceptional events in your code.

Comment: But how do I distinguish between the two?

Comment: The other answer explains it. While the point of my answer is that there is no point in distinguishing these (way more than two actually) exception types. Every one have to be logged yet every one have to trigger a generic 503 error page to be shown.